# get ID of latest records in a group by linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

This linq query below contains some join and I need to get latest record Id of one entity, its Id field of 'sonuc'

```
var query = (from type1 in lohusaHastaRepo
    join type2 in hastaRepo on lohusa.HastaTC equals hasta.HastaTC
    join type3 in gebeSonucBildirimRepo on lohusa.HastaTC equals sonuc.HastaTC
    group type1 by hasta.HastaTC into grp
    select new SomeModel()
    {
        Type3ID = 0,//I want to get 'ID' of latest records of 'sonuc' entity 
        Type1ID = grp.OrderByDescending(o=>o.BirthDate).Select(s=>s.ID).FirstOrDefault()
    });
```

This:

```
grp.OrderByDescending(o=>o.DogumTarihiResmi).Select(s=>s.ID).FirstOrDefault()
```

above gives me Id of 'type1' entity, I also need Id of 'type3'.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Comment: @nvoigt I edited post hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think this ought to work:

```
var query = (from type1 in lohusaHastaRepo
    join type2 in hastaRepo on lohusa.HastaTC equals hasta.HastaTC
    join type3 in gebeSonucBildirimRepo on lohusa.HastaTC equals sonuc.HastaTC
    group new {type1, type3} by hasta.HastaTC into grp
    select new SomeModel()
    {
        Type3ID = grp
            .Select(e => e.type3)
            .OrderByDescending(o=>o.BirthDate)
            .Select(s=>s.ID)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        Type1ID = grp
            .Select(e => e.type1)
            .OrderByDescending(o=>o.BirthDate)
            .Select(s=>s.ID)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
    });
```

I can't say how well it will perform, though. You might want to test it on a large data set, and consider splitting it into two separate round-trips:

```
var type1IDs = sonuc.GroupBy(s => s.HastaTC)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        HastaTC = g.Key,
        ID = g.OrderByDescending(o=>o.BirthDate)
            .Select(s=>s.ID)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    });

var type3IDs = lohusa.GroupBy(s => s.HastaTC)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        HastaTC = g.Key,
        ID = g.OrderByDescending(o=>o.BirthDate)
            .Select(s=>s.ID)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    });
```